# Trivial norm and topology

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

It's a well known fact that every norm in finite dimensional vector spaces are equivalent. So these norms have to induce the same topology, right? My question is If I take, for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space and put the trivial metric $d: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:

$$d(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } x=y \\
  1 & \mbox { otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$$

The topology induced by it is the discrete one, but if you take the Euclidean norm, for example, the topology induced is not the discrete! What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Every norm induces a metric, not the other way around. The discrete metric does not arise from a norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your metric is not induced by a norm. A norm satisfies $\|cx\| = \mid c\mid \|x\|$ and $\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$. Then the associated distance is $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

For your distance, if it was associated to a norm, you would have had  for $x\neq y$ $d(2x,2y)=1=2 \|x-y\|=2d(x,y)=2$. Impossible.